# Java. Удаление слова из txt файла

Tags: java, файлы

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Использую следующие методы для записи информации в файл и чтения из него:

```
   public static void PrintToFile(String ManufacturerFilePath, String NewManufacturer) {
    File file = new File(ManufacturerFilePath);
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        writer.write(NewManufacturer);
        writer.write("\r\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//Чтение из файла.
public static void ReadFromFile() {
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\Warehouse\\ManufacturerList.txt")) {
        int readIt;
        while ((readIt = reader.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) readIt);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

В txt записывается информация в следующем виде:

Производитель1

Производитель2

Производитель3

Хочу использовать метод, который будет удалять производителя из файла (без перезаписи в новый файл) исходя из введенного пользователем названия производителя.
Т.е. пользователь вводить "Производитель2" - удаляю его из txt файл. Получаю в итоге файл с содержанием:

Производитель1

Производитель3

Кажется понял, как удалять строки из файла, но для этого необходимо:

1. Сравнить производителя, которого ввел пользователь с тем, что есть в файле.
2. В случае соответствия - найти строку.
3. Удалить строку.

Но возможно ли сделать проще? Т.е. найти в файле слово, которое соответствует введенному пользователем и удалить его?

P.S. В этом совсем новичок, поэтому буду особенно благодарен за простые решения :)

Сообщение для обхода ограничения правки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смею предположить, что файл - внешняя для вашего приложения структура. Поэтому так или иначе его нужно прочитать в массив байт, или построчной или каким нибудь другим способом. Далее определить вхождение первого и последнего байта(строки) и удалить из массива байт(массива строк). 
И придется записать обратно(хоть и не в другой файл, но все же полный контент положить обратно в файл).

Comment: RandomAccesFile позволит найти байты искомого лова, и тут же их подменить. Но удаление приведет к сдвигу массива следующих байт.